# android 10 : android.process.media keeps stopping when invoke downloadmanager

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-10.0

Recently I start testing my app in Android 10 (it works fine on the previous version). When I invoke download manager for a file, I got a crash with a message:

> android.process.media keeps stopping

This is my snippet code:

```
String mFilePath = "file://"
                    + FileManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDir()
                    + "/"
                    + fileName
                    + extension;
Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(fileUrl);
DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
req.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(mFilePath));
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
dm.enqueue(req);
```

What's the exact problem? How can I report this error to Gooogle?

Comment: "What's the exact problem?" -- the download service may not have access to your requested location. What exactly is `mFilePath`?

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have already granted permission for writing storage. Sorry about snippet code, I missed one line `req.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(mFilePath));`

Comment: The logcat does not show error, so I can not trace where the problem started

Comment: "I have already granted permission for writing storage" -- you do not have a way of doing that. What exactly is the value of `mFilePath`?

Comment: @CommonsWare: For eg: file:///storage/emulated/0/<app_folder>/<file_name>.mp4

Comment: I doubt that the download service has access to that location. On Android 10, apps -- including system apps like the download service -- have limited access to external storage. Personally, I don't use `DownloadManager` much, preferring to download things in-app using OkHttp.

Comment: Okay, thank for providing information

Comment: This problem is also occuring in non-android 10 devices.